# Why do some websockets require a second `await` to get a successful response?

Tags: python, json, websocket, python-asyncio

I'm using a very simple python websocket api call below:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json

msg = {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "public/get_index_price", "id": 42, "params": {"index_name": "btc_usd"}}

async def call_api(msg):
    async with websockets.connect('wss://test.deribit.com/ws/api/v2') as websocket:
        await websocket.send(msg)
        response = await websocket.recv()
        print(response)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(call_api(json.dumps(msg)))
```

which returns the following successful response:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":42,"result":{"index_price":43497.69,"estimated_delivery_price":43497.69},"usIn":1649286272811228,"usOut":1649286272811333,"usDiff":105,"testnet":true}
```

However, when I use the code for a different api below:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json

msg = {"op": "subscribe", "args": [{"channel": "instruments", "instType": "FUTURES"}]}

async def call_api(msg):
    async with websockets.connect('wss://wspap.okx.com:8443/ws/v5/public?brokerId=9999') as websocket:
        await websocket.send(msg)
        response = await websocket.recv()
        print(response)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(call_api(json.dumps(msg)))
```

The response is the same json message that I have sent and I cannot understand why:

```
{"event":"subscribe","arg":{"channel":"instruments","instType":"FUTURES"}}
```

Looking at other code for the api I have managed to find that if I add a second `response = await websocket.recv()` I do manage to get the desired response as you can see in the code below:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json

msg = {"op": "subscribe", "args": [{"channel": "instruments", "instType": "FUTURES"}]}

async def call_api(msg):
    async with websockets.connect('wss://wspap.okx.com:8443/ws/v5/public?brokerId=9999') as websocket:
        await websocket.send(msg)
        response = await websocket.recv()
        response = await websocket.recv()
        print(response)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(call_api(json.dumps(msg)))
```

The successful response which I have shortened:

```
{'arg': {'channel': 'instruments', 'instType': 'FUTURES'}, 'data': [{'alias': 'this_week', 'baseCcy': '', 'category': '2', 'ctMult': '1', 'ctType': 'inverse', 'ctVal': '10', 'ctValCcy': 'USD', 'expTime': '1649404800000', 'instId':
```

My question is why do I need a addtional `response = await websocket.recv()` ? Why isn't a single `await` sufficient as it is in the first api example given at the beginning?

Comment: Looking at their [documentation](https://www.okx.com/docs-v5/en/#websocket-api-subscribe) the behaviour is correct. Upon `subscribe` the server returns confirmation (`subscribe` or `error`) and then next `recv()` will receive the actual message.

Comment: @AndrejKesely ok I can see the `subcribe` but I don't where it says anything about the next `recv` ?

Comment: It's in the `Return parameters`. The return parameters are received with first `recv()`. The second `recv()` will receive actual data.

Comment: @AndrejKesely ok thanks very much for clarifying. I'm new to websockets so didn't seem obvious to me.